# Google Apps Script. JSON to Spreadsheet - Result too long (API to Sheet) Work only with 100 reg

Tags: json, google-apps-script

Good morning, I have made a Script that connects with an APi, it returns a JSON, I serialize it and complete an array with it .. then I paste it in a Google Spreadsheet, but it only works with 100 records. However if in the same Script, under the JSON my Google Drive makes it complete.
When I check the Logger it tells me the result is too long ...

My code.

```
function getOT() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('OT');
  var url ='https://app.XXXXX.com/api/work_orders';
  var authorization=XXXXXXApi(XXX,'app.XXXXXX.com','/api/work_orders','GET','443');
  var Options ={
  "url": "https://app.XXXXXX.com/api/work_orders",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {  "Authorization": "Hawk id=\""+authorization.cID+"\", ts=\""+ authorization.cTS+"\", nonce=\""+authorization.cNONCE+"\", mac=\""+authorization.cHMAC+"\"",
  },
};

 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://app.XXXX.com/api/work_orders', Options);
 var array = [];
 var CC = response.getContentText();
 var datos = JSON.parse(CC);
 Logger.log (CC)

 for (var i = 0; i < datos.data.length ;i++) {
  array.push([datos.data[i]['wo_folio']],[datos.data[i]['description']],[datos.data[i]['personnel_description']],[datos.data[i]['items_log_description']])
  
 };
           
  for (var i = 0; i < datos.data.length ;i++){
     var startrow=2 + +i;
    sheet.getRange(startrow, 1).setValue(datos.data[i]['wo_folio']);
    sheet.getRange(startrow, 2).setValue(datos.data[i]['description']);
    sheet.getRange(startrow, 3).setValue(datos.data[i]['personnel_description']);
    sheet.getRange(startrow, 4).setValue(datos.data[i]['items_log_description']);
   }
 
DriveApp.createFile('XX.csv', CC); //copio el JSON a mi drive

}
```

Comment: About `but it only works with 100 records.`, if an error occurs, can you show it?

Comment: Is the error `Logging output too large. Truncating output.`? If not, could you please add the error to the question?

Comment: Yeesss.. The error is. "Logging output too large. Truncating output."
do you know why ...
If I write the JSON to the drive, it makes it complete. I understand that the error is made by the parse.

Comment: If I change, "datos.data.length" x 100... same..but, if i write more than 100, like 105.... Console say "TypeError: Cannot read property 'wo_folio' of undefined (línea 32, archivo "Código")"

Comment: I think I tried everything ... please, if you come up with something I would appreciate it

Comment: Hey @JuanSebastian I didn't see your comment. Make sure to mention people (like I did) so they get a notification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Logging output too large. Truncating output.` message is not an error, it's just a notice. It simply doesn't show the entire data, only a subset. This means that the data is actually there but is not shown to you when using a single call. Try logging the output inside a loop and print all the elements.

As for the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'wo_folio' of undefined`, it seems that this happens because you are modifying increasing the length property of `datos.data`:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b']
array.length = 3
console.log(array) // outputs ['a', 'b', empty]
```

Notice that if I try to get the third element of array 2, you'll get `undefined`. In a similar way, `datos.data[i]['wo_folio']` will become `undefined['wo_folio']` if iterated outside the original length, and thus the error is thrown. And just so you know, changing an array length via its `length` property is rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

I have put the size of the data, and I figure 100

```
var CC = response.getContentText();
var datos = JSON.parse(CC);
var registros=datos.data;
Logger.log(registros.length);
```

[21-01-03 00:19:21:398 ART] 100.0  .. but i have too many more...

If I run the query from postman, it has more than 300 records .. it only happens when I query it from GAS