# Apps Script - How to solve a truncated output from the console

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Following my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73467721/apps-script-export-json-properly-into-google-sheet/73468143?noredirect=1#comment129741116_73468143) where I was trying to export my JSON data to a Google Sheet,
I now have an issue with my output being truncated. Basically my Google sheet will only displays 100 rows at a time.

When I enter `console.log(jsonData);`, The console gives me the following message: `Logging output too large. Truncating output.`

I believe I need the output to be put inside a loop in order to load all the elements.

If anyone knows how to do this in Apps Script, I would be very grateful.

Edit: The message I receive from the console is not an error, it's just a notice from Google Apps script.
I need to find how can I log the entire output of my response in my script, so all my data can be exported and not only the first 100 rows.

Comment: From your question, in that case, how about exporting the data as a text file? In this case, how about putting `DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", response.getContentText())` after the line of `UrlFetchApp.fetch`? By this, you can see a text file in the root folder. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike, Sorry, let me reformulate my question. Because `Logging output too large. Truncating output.` then my Google sheet will export only what is displayed in the console (only 100 rows). My issue is the same as this person: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65444065/google-apps-script-json-to-spreadsheet-result-too-long-api-to-sheet-work-on but my Javascript expertise is too low, so I cannot adapt this to my script, sorry about that ...

Comment: If you just want to see what the jsonData is, if its a string, split it on '{' or some other character, convert to a 2D array and then setValues() to some place on a sheet.  Just because the console or Logger can't handle a large number of lines doesn't mean its not there.

Comment: As the duplicate says, export the text to drive, if you want. As TheWizEd says, data is actually present in memory and you can export it to drive or a Google sheet.